# Advanced Custom Fields and functions

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm quite new to php and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (ACF). I want to display a static banner on all pages except on the homepage which has a video. How do I use the if main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     <?php if (is_home()) { //check is home page
     //not show
     } else { //if not home page
     //show ACF 
    the_field('field_name'); //replace ACF field name
   }
   ?>
```

Good Luck